# Prepend String using perl/awk/sed?

Tags: perl, regex, sed, awk

I'm trying to script a change to my apache config file (httpd.conf). I'm trying to match the following string:

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
```

And PREPEND the following text:

```
#
# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
# with the URL of http://servername/server-status
# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
#
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ip6-localhost 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
</Location>
```

My understanding is that sed doesn't support multiple line matches, awk seems difficult to do multiple line matches. I'm trying to get perl to work with perl -0777 -pi -e but I can't seem to figure out a regular expression that matches the original pattern.

I'd prefer to do this as a one liner - not a script because i want it to be portable (i.e. copy and paste as needed).

Any perl regex experts out there that can help me devise a solution?

Many thanks in advance
Brad

**EDIT**

The following works:

```
 sed -i -e ':begin;$!N;s/#\n# DirectoryIndex/#\n# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,\n# with the URL of http:\/\/servername\/server-status\n# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.\n#\n<Location \/server-status>\n\tSetHandler server-status\n\tOrder deny,allow\n\tDeny from all\n\tAllow from localhost ip6-localhost 192\.168\.0\.0\/255\.255\.255\.0\n<\/Location>\n\n#\n\#DirectoryIndex/;tbegin;P;‌​D' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

But there's no space between the # and DirectoryIndex.

However if I try to change it to:

```
sed -i -e ':begin;$!N;s/#\n# DirectoryIndex/#\n# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,\n# with the URL of http:\/\/servername\/server-status\n# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.\n#\n<Location \/server-status>\n\tSetHandler server-status\n\tOrder deny,allow\n\tDeny from all\n\tAllow from localhost ip6-localhost 192\.168\.0\.0\/255\.255\.255\.0\n<\/Location>\n\n#\n\# DirectoryIndex/;tbegin;P;‌​D' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

The sed command hangs and never finishes. I can't seem to figure out why?

The only difference is a space between # and DirectoryIndex.

Comment: It look like a Stack over flow question ?

Comment: You can use replace `#\n# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory` by this + new text, you don't need a reg exp for that | or you can get the line of this text and append after what you want.

Comment: Thanks i've flagged it and proposed it be migrated to stackoverflow. I wasn't sure weather to use stackoverflow, serverfault, or linux/unix site.

Comment: It's perfectly fine here. This is a sysadmin task.

Comment: @Froggiz - sed won't do multiline matches though. And trying to do what you propose with perl is failing:

Comment: # perl -0777 -pi -e '/#\n# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory/foo/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/#\n# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory/foo"
        (Missing operator before foo?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "/#\n# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory/foo"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: This works:

sed -i -e ':begin;$!N;s/#\n# DirectoryIndex/#\n# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,\n# with the URL of http:\/\/servername\/server-status\n# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.\n#\n<Location \/server-status>\n\tSetHandler server-status\n\tOrder deny,allow\n\tDeny from all\n\tAllow from localhost ip6-localhost 192\.168\.0\.0\/255\.255\.255\.0\n<\/Location>\n\n#\n\#DirectoryIndex/;tbegin;P;D' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

But there's no space between the # and DirectoryIndex.

Comment: If I try to change it to:

sed -i -e ':begin;$!N;s/#\n# DirectoryIndex/#\n# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,\n# with the URL of http:\/\/servername\/server-status\n# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.\n#\n<Location \/server-status>\n\tSetHandler server-status\n\tOrder deny,allow\n\tDeny from all\n\tAllow from localhost ip6-localhost 192\.168\.0\.0\/255\.255\.255\.0\n<\/Location>\n\n#\n\# DirectoryIndex/;tbegin;P;‌​D' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 

(The only difference is a space between # and DirectoryIndex.)

Comment: The sed command hangs and never finishes. I can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: Escape the hashes, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk, how about:

- store every line in a variable for "the previous line"
- if the current line matches the second one you're looking for (DirectoryIndex), check the variable with the previous line
- If they both match

  - print the bumpf
  - print the 'current line'
  - print the swallowed '#'
- Else

  - print the current line
- update the 'previous line' variable with the current line.

This should work for you because you don't strictly need to PREPEND the text - since both the text you're looking for and the text you're inserting start with `#` you can leave the original `#`, insert your text minus the first `#` line in the middle, then print the original second line, then print another `#` to be the one you didn't prepend.

You'll have to fill in the full text, but there's enough here to convince me it can work ;)

```
gawk "{if (a==\"#\" && /^# DirectoryIndex/) {print \"# Allow Server\n#With the URL\n#\"; print $0} else {print $0}} {a=$0}" httpd.conf > ??
```

(My double quote escapes are for Windows' command prompt. Adjust as necessary).

Edited quoting for bash:

```
gawk '{if (a=="#" && /^# DirectoryIndex/) {print "# Allow Server\n# With the URL\n#"; print $0} else {print $0}} {a=$0}' httpd.conf
```

Comment: This just outputs a string of zeros for me: 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: That's part of the "adjust the quoting for your shell" bit.... I've edited my answer with a different quoting, and it seems to work on bash like that.

Comment: I have this working sorta. When I run the gawk statement it empties my config file.

Comment: gawk '{if (a=="#" && /^# DirectoryIndex/) {print "# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,\n# with the URL of http://servername/server-status\n# Change the \".example.com\" to match your domain to enable.\n#\n<Location /server-status>\n\tSetHandler server-status\n\tOrder deny,allow\n\tDeny from all\n\tAllow from localhost ip6-localhost 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0\n</Location>\n\n#"; print $0} else {print $0}} {a=$0}' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf > /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Maybe you can't read and write the same file at once - one of these http://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/478656 answers could help?

Comment: Ugly but this works: my_output="$(gawk '{if (a=="#" && /^# DirectoryIndex/) {print "# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,\n# with the URL of http://servername/server-status\n# Change the \".example.com\" to match your domain to enable.\n#\n<Location /server-status>\n\tSetHandler server-status\n\tOrder deny,allow\n\tDeny from all\n\tAllow from localhost ip6-localhost 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0\n</Location>\n\n#"; print $0} else {print $0}} {a=$0}' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)" && echo "$my_output" > /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Cool.  btw. you can use code formatting in comments with backticks `like \`xyz\``

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
perl -0777 -i.original -pe 's/#\n# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory/#\n# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory\n#\n# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,\n# with the URL of http:\/\/servername\/server-status\n# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.\n#\n<Location \/server-status>\n    SetHandler server-status\n    Order deny,allow\n    Deny from all\n    Allow from localhost ip6-localhost 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0\/255.255.255.0\n<\/Location>/igs' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Don't forget to escape your string `replace` (`\/` for `/`) when you are using / delimiter in regexp tool

If you are running it through shell, you can do a script like that

```
#Set serach delimiter
search='#\n# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory'

#Set replace string from file
replace=$search"\n"$(cat newConfFile)

#Escape "/" char
replace=${replace//\//\\\/ }

#Launch the script
perl -0777 -i.original -pe 's/${search}/${replace}/igs' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

With newConfFile containt the virtual host configuration you want to add

This is a Bash Function to test if a function exist

```
#return 0 if command exist else return 1
canExec()
{
type "$1" &> /dev/null ;
}
```

for example `canExec sed` test if sed command exist on your system

Comment: This part is actually a block of text which I truncated:
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory

So really its:

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# More Stuff
# And More

So what the above does is sandwich it right in the middle of the statement:

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory

   {Puts contents here}

# More Stuff
# And More

Comment: How you get the default string where to put your data after, can it be set as variable or even external file ? how you will launch your command, in a program ?

Comment: I'm looking to create a one-liner (mind you a very long one liner) which can be copied and pasted (as needed) into a bash prompt. Assuming the user has sed/awk/perl already installed.

Comment: I'm indifferent as to weather it uses sed or awk or perl - i have it ALMOST working in sed (per the comments in the original post) but the spacing isn't quite right and when I try and correct it sed hangs.

Comment: sed & hawk are almost all the time on any linux system, but perl need a package for it. If you need you can test if command exist in bash i addeded a func in my post

Comment: the perl command i posted, worked for me, maybe you can post your sed command to have help to fix it

Comment: The sed command is in the original post comments (above).

Comment: can you make an update of your original post with it plz ? it is hard to read in comments

Comment: Original post edited.